# Can i merge multiple m3u8 files into one m3u8 file?

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have multiple m3u8 files which I want to play one after another in the same video player. Is there a way to include all of them in one m3u8 file?
For example, let's say that I have these files: zebra.m3u8, giraffe.m3u8 and lion.m3u8, how can I play all of them one after another in the same player?

I was thinking about an m3u8 file which will work like this:

```
zebra.m3u8 -> master playlist -> media playlist
giraffe.m3u8 ...
```

Some kind of file which will contain the manifests' urls for the m3u8 clips.

Edit:
An idea which came to mind was to list the .ts urls of all clips in the correct order and create sort of a merged m3u8 playlist but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by using the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-4.3.2.3

Comment: You are awesome !

Comment: Is it also possible to combine them in a way that a player treats it a single video? With the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag players seem to play each segment as a separate video.